# How to gather IP and User Agent info from web log with AWK?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed, awk, log-analysis

I have a log file, containing text like:

```
66.249.74.18 - - [21/Apr/2013:05:55:33 +0000] 200 "GET /1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 7691 "-" "Googlebot-Image/1.0" "-"
220.181.108.96 - - [21/Apr/2013:05:55:33 +0000] 200 "GET /1.html HTTP/1.1" 17722 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)" "-"
```

I want to collect all the ip and user agent info to a file:

```
66.249.74.18 "Googlebot-Image/1.0"
220.181.108.96 "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
```

How can I do it with awk?

I know `awk '{print $1}'` can list all ips and `awk -F\" '{print $6}'` can list all User Agent, but I have no idea how to combine them into output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A portable approach not using GNU extensions:

```
awk '{printf "%s ",$1;for(i=12;i<NF;i++)printf "%s ",$i;printf "\n"}' file
```

Comment: it returns： "66.249.74.18" "GET /1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 7691 "-" "Googlebot-Image/1.0" 
"220.181.108.96" "GET /1.html HTTP/1.1" 17722 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)" but awk '{printf "%s ",$1;for(i=7;i<NF;i++)printf "%s ",$i;printf "\n"}' test.log | awk  -F\" '{print $2" " $8}' can get what I want. Can you make it shorter?

Comment: @user432506 yes, you want from `i=12` see update. If this solves your problem please upvote and accept this answer, to accept the accept the answer you click the tick mark next to the question, this will show the question as solved.

Comment: how to select particular date data from file using awk command @iiSeymour

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F' - |\\"' '{print $1, $7}' temp1
```

output:

```
66.249.74.18 Googlebot-Image/1.0
220.181.108.96 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible;Baiduspider/2.0;+http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)
```

temp1 file:

```
66.249.74.18 - - [21/Apr/2013:05:55:33 +0000] 200 "GET /1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 7691 "-" "Googlebot-Image/1.0" "-"
220.181.108.96 - - [21/Apr/2013:05:55:33 +0000] 200 "GET /1.html HTTP/1.1" 17722 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"     "-"
```

Answer (score 2):

```sh
awk '{print $1,$6}' FPAT='(^| )[0-9.]+|"[^"]*"'
```

- define a field as

  - start with beginning of line or space
  - followed by `[0-9.]+` or `"[^"]*"`
- then print fields 1 and 6

Comment: Is there a way to add quote marks to the ip fields first? Then I could use awk -F\" '{print $2 $8}' to get the right result.

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl`:

```
perl -nle '/^((?:\d+\.?){4})(?:.+?"){4}\s+(".*?")/ && print "$1 $2"' access_log
```

The trick lies on counting *chars that are not double quote + double quote*: `(?:.+?"){4}`. Here's a visual description of the regexp: https://regex101.com/r/xP0kF4/4

The regexp is more complex than previous answers but we could *easily* parse other properties.